# TextBox Borders in Reporting Services (Report Builder 3.0)

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, border, reportbuilder

I have a report that I am creating in Report Builder 3.0 that I appear unable to set the color value (or any value) on TextBoxes Borders.

I have a list that I have added a text box to.  I then click on the text box and select Text Box Properties ... then click Border, the value for Color: is Black.  If I change this value to anything else and then click OK, then come back into Text Box properties it is set back to Black.  Any idea what is going on here?  Is this not the correct way to set a border color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like when changing the Border color you need to follow the following procedure (if doing a color change or if trying to do an expression to get that color)

- Change Color (or create expression)
- Click None (for no border)
- Click Outline (for border)
- Click OK

Not sure why you need to remove and re-add the border (outline), but this appears to fix the issue.  If you do not remove and re-add the border (outline) it looks like it reverts to the default (which in my case was black).

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the tablix border to None and then set each cell border to Solid. Making any changes to the tablix then the cell makes the Default come back since you have not set the tablix border to None.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem (except I wanted the border widths changed).

In testing HDog's answer, I've discovered that the reason you need to re-add the border after making changes to the properties is so that you can select the actual border you want to apply the changes to.

For example, if you want a white border on the left and a blue border on the right, select None (for no borders), change the color property to white, select the left border (it will show in white), change the color property to blue, and select the right border (it will show in blue).  Then click "OK".

If you come back to the border properties for that cell, you will see the color property set back to black, but the actual borders you change still in the color you set them to.